# How to use unicode in sed?

Tags: regex, bash, unicode, sed

I want to convert a txt file to html using sed.

However, to match html syntax, I need to include tags (and thus < and >). When I use these characters in my sed expression, sed thinks I'm specifying the source or target file, even if I escape them with . I keep getting the message "The system cannot find the file specified".

How can I avoid this? Can I somehow use the unicode number?

Source file: input.txt

Content:

```
Hello world!
```

Desired target file: output.htm

Content:

```
<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>
```

sed command that doesn't work:

```
sed -r 's#(.*)#\<html\>\<body\>\1\<\/body\>\<\/html\>#g' <input.txt >output.htm
```

Comment: for such simple case you don't need sed

Comment: Well, [`sed -r 's#(.*)#<html><body>\1</body></html>#g'`](https://ideone.com/dpMnsC) works.

Answer (score 2):

With simple `shell`'s **`printf`** function:

```
printf "<html><body>%s</body></html>\n" "$(< input.txt)" > output.htm
```

The `output.htm` contents:

```
<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>
```

---

If you still need ***`sed`*** approach (by some purposes):

```
echo -e "<html><body>\n</body></html>" | sed '1 r input.txt' > output.htm
```

- `1 r input.txt` - `r` command here will read and insert the contents of `input.txt` after the `1`st line of the passed html content (lines delimited by `\n`)

The `output.htm` contents:

```
<html><body>
Hello world!
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep it more simple as follows.

```
echo "<html><body>" && cat Input_file && echo "</body></html>"
```

Output will be as follows.

```
<html><body>
Hello world!
</body></html>
```